PowerQuery with WebAction.Request not working
I am trying to retrieve JSON from your ERP. I need to send a "body" content with appropriate filter data. ERP expects a PATCH method.
I can only use Source = Json.Document(WebAction.Request(WebMethod.Patch, url, options)), for Patch.
Yet: I always get:Expression.Error: We haven't been given permission to perform actions against this resource.
and there is not authorization required as I send the Bearer in the header.
Almost identical (reg. url/bearer, just no body) GET call  works just fine with Web.Contents.
Any idea how I can trick WebAction.Request into being accepted by PowerQuery too?
